# How to make clicked Jquery collapsible div stick to the top

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery collapsible div for my Application .
My requirement is to

I'm trying to make , the clicked elemnt of the Jquery collapasable div gets fixed to the top" and when you are scrolled back up for it to be in view it resumes being fixed and goes back to being displayed as block.

My attempt to make this is as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/4/

```
<div data-role="content" class="data">
        <div class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false"  data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Header 1</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>

        </div>

         <div class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false"  data-role="collapsible"  >
            <h3>Header 2</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

           </div>



$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function() {

    $('.my-collaspible').not(this).collapsible("collapse")
  });
  $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsiblecollapse', function() {});
});
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: any purpose of this line`$('.my-collaspible').on('collapsiblecollapse', function() {});`

Comment: then why you put this line?